# htaccess and Google sitemap.xml files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Spent some time searching here and on the web in general, but can't find a clear answer to my question. Hoping that this is a relevant question for this forum and that some one can help me.

I recently converted my HTML site to WordPress and want to run WP from a sub-directory.

Except for the index.html file I've removed old site files from server root and added a Redirect 301 to sub-directory:

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://www.currentsite.com/folder/
```

This is working fine.

My question is, do I need to update my Google sitemap.xml file (which still currently points to old - deleted- files in server root at www.currentsite.com)? ... or does the redirect take care of this?

Or, to put it another way, how does a .htaccess redirect affect Google search engine?

Note:

I know that WordPress document a method of running a WP install from a sub-directory (http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)  but I couldn't get that to work so I created my own htaccess redirect.

Mekong

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. If you put your site main directory to sub then you need to redirect old url to new url but in google not accept your changes until you not submit google site map.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

This plugin use to generate sitemap and generated sitemap submit to google google crawl your new url.